# converting data frame to list of lists

Tags: r, list

I have a simple dataframe that I am trying to convert to a list of lists, while also combining several of the columns into a numeric vector for each row. For example, the dataframe looks like this:

```
Site       c1       c2       c3
MUT      -3.71     1.93     0.26
MBT      -2.82     2.52     0.58
MFW      -1.67     1.60    -0.09
```

reproducible with this:

```
regression <- structure(list(site = structure(1:3, .Label = c("MUT", "MBT", 
"MFW", "EUT", "EFW", "EBT", "PBT", "PUT", "PFW"), class = "factor"), 
    c1 = c(-3.71, -2.82, -1.67), c2 = c(1.93, 2.52, 1.6), c3 = c(0.26, 
    0.58, -0.09)), .Names = c("site", "c1", "c2", "c3"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to make a list out of each row, combining columns "c1", "c2", and "c3" into a numeric vector named, say, "params" with each of the values named "c1", "c2", etc...

Desired output would look like this (not sure how to write it legibly other than dput)

```
desired <- list(structure(list(name = "MUT", params = structure(c(-3.71, 
1.93, 0.26), .Names = c("c1", "c2", "c3"))), .Names = c("name", 
"params")), structure(list(name = "MBT", params = structure(c(-2.82, 
2.52, 0.58), .Names = c("c1", "c2", "c3"))), .Names = c("name", 
"params")), structure(list(name = "MFW", params = structure(c(-1.67, 
1.6, -0.09), .Names = c("c1", "c2", "c3"))), .Names = c("name", 
"params")))
```

I messed around a bit with split, but it produced a list of data frames, and more importantly I still couldn't work out a way to combine the columns in the call. I'm new to lists, so there's probably some simple way to do this I don't know.
Thanks,

Comment: Can you post a sample of your desired output?

Comment: Maybe this: `apply(regression, 1, function(x) list(name = unname(x[1]), params = as.numeric(x[2:4])))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not exactly clear, but the following *sounds* like what you might be looking for:

```
> lapply(split(regression[-1], seq_len(nrow(regression))), unlist)
$`1`
   c1    c2    c3 
-3.71  1.93  0.26 

$`2`
   c1    c2    c3 
-2.82  2.52  0.58 

$`3`
   c1    c2    c3 
-1.67  1.60 -0.09 

> str(lapply(split(regression[-1], seq_len(nrow(regression))), unlist))
List of 3
 $ 1: Named num [1:3] -3.71 1.93 0.26
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
 $ 2: Named num [1:3] -2.82 2.52 0.58
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
 $ 3: Named num [1:3] -1.67 1.6 -0.09
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
```

---

Now that you've posted some sample output, a slight variation:

```
out <- lapply(split(regression, seq_len(nrow(regression))), 
              function(x) list(name = as.character(x[[1]]),
                               params = unlist(x[-1])))
str(out)
# List of 3
#  $ 1:List of 2
#   ..$ name  : chr "MUT"
#   ..$ params: Named num [1:3] -3.71 1.93 0.26
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
#  $ 2:List of 2
#   ..$ name  : chr "MBT"
#   ..$ params: Named num [1:3] -2.82 2.52 0.58
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
#  $ 3:List of 2
#   ..$ name  : chr "MFW"
#   ..$ params: Named num [1:3] -1.67 1.6 -0.09
#   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:3] "c1" "c2" "c3"
```

Comment: Works great. Will take me a minute to wrap my head around why, exactly. Thanks!